# Why am I gettting errors when trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2 onto Dell PowerEdge R510?

Tags: bios, operating-systems, windows-server-2012-r2, dell-poweredge

I have a new Dell PowerEdge R510 rack server that I am trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2 onto.
The machine has all 12 slots filled with 3TB hard drives.

**I've created 2 virtual disks:**

1. Disk 0/ Disk 1 - RAID 1;
2. OS to be installed on Disk 0 Disk 2 - Disk
3. 10 - RAID 5 Disk 11 has been selected for my Hot Swap.

I've got a copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 installation CD in a CD ROM drive attached via USB connection.

I've gone through the BIOS and altered the boot sequence, so that the CD ROM drive is first in the boot order (so the machine does recognize the CD ROM).

I get the following error message:

> No boot device available. Current boot mode is set to B IOS. Please
>   ensure compatible bootable media is available. Use the system setup
>   program to change the boot ode as needed.

I tried going through through **System Services - Unified Server Configurator**

- OS Deployment
- Deploy OS

I get the following:

> Unable to find a device capable of reading the operating system
>   install media Do one of the following:

1. Verify that an optical device is enabled in the BIOS
2. Install an optical device
3. Enable iDRAC virtual Media

What am I do wrong here?
I thought it should just boot up off the CD ROM.

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: Have you switched your server to UEFI mode, so you are able to install Windows Server, while on a GPT disk?  The alternative is to make a bootable installation media compatible with MBR.

Comment: Is the cdrom recognized by the bios? if so, it will be listed in the boot order. if it is listed in the boot order then specify it as the boot device.

Comment: Larryc - CD Rom is recognized and listed in the boot order. I moved it to 1st in the boot order in the BIOS setup. I mentioned that above.

Comment: Ramhound - Can you give more details on your comments?  I just finished initializing all my 3TB drives through Setup. I should switch my server to UEFI mode to install OS from Microsoft CD ROM? Newbie here.

Comment: Ramhound - I had couple of issues. Bootable ISO disk was bad, so I created a bootable USB. I also had to change the boot mode from BIOS to UEFI. Thanks for the tip! JB